# error while installing firebase-tools

Tags: node.js, npm, firebase-tools

I am trying to install firebase-tools, but I am getting following error

```
root@dell-Inspiron-3542:/home/dell# npm install -g firebase-tools
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: async@1.0.0     (node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-emulator /node_modules/async):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: sha1-+PwEyjoTeErenhZBr5hXjPvWR6k= integrity checksum failed when using sha1: wanted sha1-+PwEyjoTeErenhZBr5hXjPvWR6k= but got sha1-MFWnerUOFFoQ4RGVO5qRs6aDFew=. (13270 bytes)

npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! sha1-BDP0TYCWgP3rYO0mDxsMJi6CpAs= integrity checksum failed when using sha1: wanted sha1-BDP0TYCWgP3rYO0mDxsMJi6CpAs= but got sha1-C7um0vYsDjQcA9NpIGhvtn7+YU0=. (21377 bytes)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2017-09-06T03_26_15_726Z-debug.log
```

My node version is v8.4.0

npm version is
    5.3.0.

*note: I use nvm to manage different node versions.*

Comment: I also got this error at first, but I run this command again and it went through. Try running console as Administrator.